# MSAL cache contains multiple ID tokens satisfying the filter requirements

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We are conducting sociability testing of our new React (v18) SPA applications in DEV and discovered an issue relating to multiple matching IdToken (see error below). We are using the latest version of the MSAL libraries.

@azure/msal-browser: 2.32.2,
@azure/msal-react: 1.5.2

Our setup is unique in the sense that we use the same azure app registration for both of our apps.

Any assistance in resolving this issue would be appreciated.

**Error**

```
ClientAuthError: multiple_matching_tokens: The cache contains multiple tokens satisfying the requirements. Call AcquireToken again providing more requirements such as authority or account..
at t [as constructor] (/aircraft-ui/main.b9f4f91dd3e752cc.esm.js:2:328717)
at new t (/aircraft-ui/main.b9f4f91dd3e752cc.esm.js:2:340847)
at t.createMultipleMatchingTokensInCacheError (/aircraft-ui/main.b9f4f91dd3e752cc.esm.js:2:342380)
at e.readIdTokenFromCache (/aircraft-ui/main.b9f4f91dd3e752cc.esm.js:2:408459)
at /aircraft-ui/main.b9f4f91dd3e752cc.esm.js:2:401953
at Array.map ()
at e.getAllAccounts (/aircraft-ui/main.b9f4f91dd3e752cc.esm.js:2:401888)
at e.getAllAccounts (/aircraft-ui/main.b9f4f91dd3e752cc.esm.js:2:615681)
at lc (/aircraft-ui/main.b9f4f91dd3e752cc.esm.js:2:630671)
at Object.ja [as useReducer] (/aircraft-ui/main.b9f4f91dd3e752cc.esm.js:2:1967211)
```

Thank you.

Application work as expected when open in isolation.

Comment: Can you share the MSAL initialization source code for both apps? Also, the error causing source code?